# Jsoup returns document even when some portion of page is not fully loaded

Tags: jsoup

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/42508/icici-bank-ltd/?").timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

This return success even when some portion of the page https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/42508/icici-bank-ltd/? is still loading

- Enable slow 3G network on and you can see spinner for tables `Valuation`, `Growth & Efficiency`

Please clarify how to make Jsoup to wait for whole of the page is loaded and not partial data is fetched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your jsoup code. The data that you are looking for is being fetched with an xhr request, so jsoup won't load it.
The data can be found in this url - https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/overview/42508 as a json file, which you can download and process.
Example code with explantaions in the comments:

```
String url = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/overview/42508";
//Must add ignoreContentType, otherwise jsoup will not fetch json
Document doc = jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
//Convert the text to json onject
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(doc.text());
//Get the two arrays that hold your data
JSONArray valuation = json.getJSONArray("valuation_overview_table_data");
JSONArray growth = json.getJSONArray("growth_overview_table_data");
System.out.println(valuation);
System.out.println(growth);
```

In order to find the url of the data I had to search through the js files in the page, until I found it in the file `script-v2__slash__stocks__slash__42621__slash__.js`.

Comment: Can you please clarify how did you debug to find data url from above mentioned js file ?  I'm jr web developer and would like to know your approach of debugging this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain, but the flow of the things was like that: First I looked up in the json files that the browser fetches, but I found nothing. Then I looked at the js files - some of them are "general stuff" files, like jquery and bootstrap, and some are unique to the site, so I've looked at the script-v2 file, which luckily is not obfuscated, and searched for keywords, like "valuation". Then I placed some breakpoints in the script and exaimned some varibles until I found the function that loads the data.

Comment: I've a follow up doubt on the same problem, I wish to fetch data from "Financials" tab https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/42508/icici-bank-ltd/#financials and from the network tab with Fetch/XHR filter, I could get url as "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/financials-annual-consolidated/42508" but this doesn't return JSON per above solution, instead it returns HTML. Is this correct url I'm looking at ?

Comment: I think that there are no rules for that. If the information that you need is in that html, them it's the right page, so you can further parse it using jsoup.