# My Jsoup parsing code can no longer find the "price" data anymore

Tags: android, html, kotlin, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing a website for the price of an item, and in my code I was using:

```
val parseId : Elements = doc2.select("#PriceSection")
val spanSelected : Elements = parseId.select("span")
stringBuilder2.append(spanSelected)
val spanToString = stringBuilder2.toString()
for(char in spanToString){
    list2.add(char)
}
val newList2 = list2.toString()
val cutString2 = newList2.substring(75,105)
```

This has worked fine for weeks, but now this doesnt seem to work and I just get everything else apart from the bit I need. I dont know how to collect the data I need (Last line of the HTML code, inside the span class) anymore. I have tried a combination of `:has` and `:contains` but I cant work out why Jsoup can not find the text anymore.

Below is the HTML code from the website:

```
<div id="PriceSection" class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-column-reverse-c1skacs4 cds-borderedTop-b1fsiv3z">
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-3-_64wlqa cds-2-_1xqs9y8 cds-2-_rro7jr" style="width: calc(100% - 1px);">

<div style="width: 100%;">
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-2-_vhy4ik" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-row-r1tfxker cds-space-between-s1vbz1 cds-0-_1t4ck38 cds-1-_uaer6w cds-1-_qem5ui" style="width: 100%;">

<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">
<button type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="1 hour" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--transparent); --interactable-hovered-background:transparent; --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.88; --interactable-pressed-background:transparent; --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.82; --interactable-disabled-background:transparent;">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: var(--foreground-muted);">1H</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">

<button type="button" aria-pressed="true" aria-label="1 day" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--primary-wash); --interactable-hovered-background:rgb(240, 243, 250); --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.98; --interactable-pressed-background:rgb(226, 229, 236); --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.92; --interactable-disabled-background:rgb(250, 252, 255);">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: rgb(181, 54, 6);">1D</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">

<button type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="1 week" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--transparent); --interactable-hovered-background:transparent; --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.88; --interactable-pressed-background:transparent; --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.82; --interactable-disabled-background:transparent;">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: var(--foreground-muted);">1W</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">

<button type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="1 month" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--transparent); --interactable-hovered-background:transparent; --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.88; --interactable-pressed-background:transparent; --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.82; --interactable-disabled-background:transparent;">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: var(--foreground-muted);">1M</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">

<button type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="1 year" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--transparent); --interactable-hovered-background:transparent; --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.88; --interactable-pressed-background:transparent; --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.82; --interactable-disabled-background:transparent;">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: var(--foreground-muted);">1Y</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-center-czxavit" style="height: fit-content;">

<button type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="ALL" class="cds-interactable-i9xooc6 cds-transparentChildren-tnzgr0o cds-focusRing-fd371rq cds-transparent-tlx9nbb cds-scaledDownState-sxr2bd6 cds-pressableResetStyles-p1yut83c" style="--interactable-border-radius:100px; --interactable-background:var(--transparent); --interactable-hovered-background:transparent; --interactable-hovered-opacity:0.88; --interactable-pressed-background:transparent; --interactable-pressed-opacity:0.82; --interactable-disabled-background:transparent;">

<span class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-label1-ln29cth cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-block-bas7n4z cds-noWrap-n1er3x1v cds-1-_fibjmj cds-1-_18ml2at cds-2-_rro7jr cds-2-_1gzxkm" style="color: var(--foreground-muted);">ALL</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-center-ca5ylan cds-space-between-s1vbz1 cds-2-_vhy4ik">
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-0-_1jhyfz6 cds-0-_x4cyln" style="flex-grow: 1;">
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-2-_rro7jr">
<div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-headline-hb7l4gg cds-foregroundMuted-f1vw1sy6 cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a">

<span>Price</span>
</div>
<div class="cds-flex-f1g67tkn cds-baseline-b1fcn5pa cds-column-ci8mx7v cds-0-_1t4ck38">
<div class="cds-typographyResets-t1xhpuq2 cds-display3-doujgnf cds-foreground-f1yzxzgu cds-transition-txjiwsi cds-start-s1muvu8a cds-tabularNumbers-t11sqpt cds-1-_qem5ui">

<span>£22,508.13</span>
</div>
<span
```

What used to happen is that I could read the "£22,508.13" inside of the span class but now I can not (bottom span class).

My code looks for a class called "PriceSection" and then looks inside "PriceSection" to get all the span classes from within. I then filter out what I dont need.

Using the same code I now get a word "Relative" which appears to be from another html class after the class which contains the information I want.

Why is Jsoup now failing to find the span class (containing the price), when it was working fine before?

Answer (score 1):

Things stop working for a reason - either the site has changed or your code has. Does your code includes all the html that you expect? If you print `doc2` (to the screen or to a file) does it have ALL the expected html?
Have you made any changes to the code lately?
Another point - don't use "magic numbers" such as 75 and 105. Since the price is in the last span you can use the the following code:

```
val el = doc2.select("#PriceSection span")
println(el?.last()?.text())
```

Comment: I have just tried your code and It does not print what I need, I just get an "X" character its almost as if certain span classes are hidden from jsoup. I have not changed my code in weeks so the site I am retreiving data from must have changed

Comment: Try to disable javascript in your browser and load the page. If it does not display the values that you need then it is being loaded dynamically and you have to think on a different solution.

Comment: I disabled javascript and most of the website has stopped working. including the bits I need. So this means Jsoup is the problem as I dont think it can parse JS.

Comment: Basically you're right, but in some cases you can still use jsoup, but it is non-trivial. You can look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75553133/jsoup-returns-document-even-when-some-portion-of-page-is-not-fully-loaded) and also at the comments.